# What is the greatest integer function, and how do you integrate it?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$[x]$ denotes the greatest integer $\leq x$. Let $f(x)=[x]$ and let $g(x)=[2x].$

I am having hard time understanding this. What is meant by "greatest integer?" Can anyone refer me to any visual/graphical explanation for $[x]?$

For example, how would we draw the graph for $f(x)=[\sqrt{x}]$?

Also I am a little confused by the including properties such as $[2x]=[x]+[x+1/2]$ and with $[3x],[4x]...$

> Lastly, how would you integrate it?

For example, what would be the evaluation of the integral of $\int_1^3{[x]dx}$ and integral of $\int_0^9[\sqrt t]dt$?

In general, I am completely confused by $[x]$ and its meaning and its functional ability. So any intuitive explanation would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Given a real number $x$, the notation $[x]$ (also often seen as $\lfloor x\rfloor$) literally means "the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$". For example, $1.2$ is not an integer. The integers are
$$\ldots,\;-4,\;-3,\;-2,\;-1,\;0,\;1,\;2,\;3,\;4,\ldots$$
We throw away all the integers that are **not** less than or equal to $1.2$:
$$\ldots,\;-4,\;-3,\;-2,\;-1,\;0,\;1\hphantom{,\;2,\;3,\;4,\ldots}$$
and take the largest one of them, which is $1$. Therefore, the greatest integer less than $1.2$ is $1$, and we write
$$\lfloor 1.2\rfloor =1.$$
(By the way, [take a look at the relevant Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).)

---

Here is a graph of $\lfloor x\rfloor$, from $x=-3$ to $x=3$:

[image]

Here is a version where I've added a graph of just the function $x$ itself (in red) and lines indicating the integers (in green).

[image]

You can see on this graph that, as we expected, $\lfloor 1.2\rfloor =1$.

---

Here is a graph of $\lfloor \sqrt{x}\rfloor$, from $x=0$ to $x=25$:

[image]

Here is a version where I've added a graph of just the function $\sqrt{x}$ itself (in red) and lines indicating the integers (in green).

[image]

Here's a check for this graph: using a calculator, we know that
$$\sqrt{20}\approx 4.47214$$
and so the largest integer that's less than or equal to $\sqrt{20}$ will be $4$.

---

Using the fact that, for any numbers $a<b<c$, 
$$\int_a^c f(x)\,dx=\int_a^bf(x)\,dx+\int_b^cf(x)\,dx,$$
we can break up the range we're integrating over into pieces where $\lfloor\;\;\rfloor$ is constant, and we do know how to integrate constants (note that the endpoints don't contribute the value of the integral; integrating over the set of $x$'s for which $a\leq x\leq b$ will give the same answer as integrating over the set of $x$'s for which $a\leq x<b$, and we denote both of these operations by $\int_a^b$). For example,
$$\int_1^3\lfloor x\rfloor\,dx=\int_1^2\lfloor x\rfloor\,dx+\int_2^3\lfloor x\rfloor\,dx=\int_1^21\,dx+\int_2^32\,dx=1+2=3.$$

Comment: "...or equal to" of course.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

The more usual notation is nowadays $\lfloor x\rfloor$. "The greatest integer that is $\le x$" means what it says. Everything will be clear once we do some examples.

The number $\lfloor 3.6\rfloor$ is the biggest integer which is $\le 3.6$. This is $3$.  So $\lfloor 3.6\rfloor=3$. Similarly, $\lfloor \pi\rfloor=3$. Also, $\rfloor 17\rfloor =17$. Informally, if $x$ is an integer, then $\lfloor x\rfloor=x$. If $x$ is not an integer, we go down until we meet the first integer. For positive $x$, that means knocking off the part after the decimal point.

But it is easy to get a little confused when we apply the greatest integer function to negative numbers. Note that $\lfloor -4.7\rfloor=-5$, since the biggest integer which is $\le -4.7$ is $-5$. Luckily, one meets $\lfloor x\rfloor$ mainly with positive $x$. 
Now let us do an integrations, such as 
$$\int_0^9 \left\lfloor \sqrt{x}\right\rfloor \,dx.$$

Let $f(x)=\left\lfloor \sqrt{x}\right\rfloor$.  First we will see what $f(x)$ looks like.

For $0\le x\lt 1$, we have $0\le \sqrt{x}\lt 1$, and therefore $\left\lfloor \sqrt{x}\right\rfloor=0$.

For $1\le x\lt 4$, we have $1\le \sqrt{x}\lt 2$, and therefore $\left\lfloor \sqrt{x}\right\rfloor =1$.

For $4\le x\lt 9$, similarly we have $\left\lfloor \sqrt{x}\right\rfloor=2$. And finally for $x=9$ we have $\left\lfloor \sqrt{x}\right\rfloor=3$.

So $f(x)$ is defined by different formulas over different parts of the world. It is $0$ in the interval $[0,1)$, and $1$ in the interval $[1,4)$, and $2$ in the interval $[4,9)$, and $0$ at $9$. You should graph $y=f(x)$ to see clearly what comes next.

To integrate, we integrate separately over our intervals, and add up. So we want
$$\int_0^1 (0)\,dx+\int_1^4 1\,dx+\int_4^9 2\,dx+\int_9^9 3\,dx.$$
The first integral and the last are both $0$. The middle two are $3$ and $10$, so our integral is $13$.  The individual integrations are easy: geometrically, we are just finding the areas of rectangles.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, $[x]$ is also known as the ceiling function.  You can think of this as the "rounding up" function.  It's also sometimes denoted $\lceil x\rceil$.  As far as graphs go, it looks [like this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ceil%28x%29&t=ff3tb01).

For your graph of the $[\sqrt{x}\,]$, you can see [that here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ceil%28sqrt%28x%29%29).

Comment: Note that in the question, it is given that $[x]\leq x,$ so I would say the desired function is the _floor_ function (aka rounding-down function), $\lfloor x\rfloor.$ The ceiling function of $x$ is the least integer that is $\geq x.$ I do find the name "greatest integer" to be a little counterintuitive, since it suggests the function's output should be an increase from its input, whereas actually it is a decrease if it is different at all.