# Antiderivative of the greatest integer function

Tags: calculus

One of my homework problem wants me to prove that the greatest integer function $f(x)= \lfloor x \rfloor$ does not have an antiderivative. While thinking, I got to this expression,

$$\int_0 ^x \lfloor t \rfloor \, dt = \frac{1}{2} \lfloor x \rfloor(2x- \lfloor x \rfloor -1) $$

> Is there an antiderivative for the greatest integer function?

The first part of the fundamental theorem of calculus implies the existence of an antiderivative for continuous functions. But what about discontinuous functions? Is there an antiderivative for any discontinuous functions?

And thank you for any hints or ideas for my homework problem.

Comment: **hint**: a function f with a discontinuity of the first kind does not have an antiderivative.

Comment: What is 'discontinuity of the first kind'?

Comment: when at a point x0 the one sided limits L+ and L- are finite and different

Comment: Strange...  I see a related topic that tells how to integrate this function...  http://math.stackexchange.com/q/408953/17976

Comment: @Mike: I have read that topic before I wrote this question. And I know how to calculate the definite integral of $[x]$. I asked about the existence of antiderivatives of discontinuous functions.

Comment: You define an antiderivative in terms of a limit, not an integral. Show that it is not possible for this limit to hold because of the jump discontinuities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor$ can be integrated, but it cannot have an antiderivative on the entire real line if we require that an antiderivative must be *differentiable everywhere*.

Suppose, towards a contradiction, that $F(x)$ were an antiderivative for $f(x)$, differentiable everywhere. By [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)), the derivative $F'(x) = f(x)$ satisfies the intermediate value property, so since $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$ there has to be some $a \in (0,1)$ such that $f(a) = \frac12$. So $\lfloor a \rfloor = \frac12$, but this is impossible.