# The greatest integer function

Tags: functions, definite-integrals

I am having hard time understanding this. What is meant by "greatest integer?" Can anyone refer me to any visual/graphical explanation for $\lfloor x\rfloor$?
I am trying with this question but could not do it.
[find the greatest integer function][1]
$$\int_{2}^6 \lfloor 3x^2\rfloor dx$$

Comment: $[x]$ (most commonly written $\lfloor x\rfloor$) is the greatest integer which is smaller or equal to $x$. For example, $[4]=4$, $[4.56]=4$, $[3.9999999]=3$, $[-3.2]=-4$, and so on.

Comment: have a look at [Floor_and_ceiling_functions][1]  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions

Comment: Another question with some useful answers about integrating the greatest integer function is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408953/what-is-the-greatest-integer-function-and-how-do-you-integrate-it

Answer (score 3):

For $x\in [2,6)$, $x\to 3x^2$ is an increasing function and it attains the values in $[3\cdot 2^2,3\cdot 6^2)=[12,108)$. For any integer $k\in [12,107]$, let
$$I_k=\{x\in [2,6): k\leq 3x^2<k+1\}=[\sqrt{k/3},\sqrt{(k+1)/3}).$$
Note that if $x\in I_k$ then $\lfloor 3x^2\rfloor=k$ which means that  $\lfloor 3x^2\rfloor$ is constant on each interval $I_k$.

Moreover
$|I_k|=\sqrt{(k+1)/3}-\sqrt{k/3}$ where $|I_k|$ is the length of $I_k$.

Hence by the definition of integral, 
$$\int_{2}^6 \lfloor 3x^2\rfloor dx=\sum_{k=12}^{107} k|I_k|
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\sum_{k=12}^{107} k(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k})
\approx 206.005$$
where $|I_k|$ is the length of the interval $I_k$.

P.S. For general information about the floor function take a look [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).

Comment: thank you so much Mr. Robert.  can you please explain more or show some steps that get you to the answer. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Sarah I edited my answer with more details. Further doubts?