# Apostol Calculus: Difficulty getting listed answer

Tags: calculus

I am working with Tom Apostol's calculus and ran into an answer I can't wrap my head around. The question is as follows:

`Compute the value of the following integral(s). The notation [x] denotes the greatest integer <=x`

The integral I'm working on is:

$ \int_{-1}^3 2[x]dx$

The answer in the back is listed as "4" but I must not be wrapping my head around the notation correctly. I keep gettin 8 as the integral of just x is 4 with the same range of integration. Any help getting to that correct value would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/408953/215011 , especially the diagram displaying the graph of the greatest integer function.

Comment: Super helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

We split the integral $$\int_{-1}^3 2[x] dx = \int_{-1}^0 2[x] dx + \int_{0}^1 2[x] dx + \int_{1}^2 2[x] dx + \int_{2}^3 2[x] dx$$

The greatest integer for any $x \in [-1, 0)$ is $-1$, and the greatest integer for any $x \in [0, 1)$ is 0 and the greatest integer for any $x \in [1, 2)$ is $1$ and the greatest integer for any $x \in [2, 3)$ is $2$.

Comment: This makes sense. I guess I missed the bit about the open and closed ranges when splitting up the integral. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

$$I=\int_{-1}^{3}2[x]dx=\int_{-1}^{0}-2dx+\int_{0}^{1}0dx+\int_{1}^{2}2dx+\int_{2}^{3}4dx$$
$$I=-2+0+2+4=4$$
Hope this helps...

Comment: These were all super helpful, thank you very much.

Comment: I am glad it helped....

Answer (score 1):

Just split it up into its constant parts
\begin{eqnarray*} \int_{-1}^3 2[x]dx
& = & 2\left(\int_{-1}^0 [x]dx
+ \int_{0}^1 [x]dx
 +\int_{1}^2 [x]dx
 +\int_{2}^3 [x]dx
 \right) \\
& = & 2\left(-1+ 0
 +1
 +2\right)\\& = & 4
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

You can break the integral apart -1 to 0 , 0 to 1... so you can know the value of [x] Then solve everything separetly.

Be careful [-0.5]=-1